# c# DllImport c++ dll error: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, c++, dll

here's my C++ code:

**ExportAPI.cpp**

```
extern "C"
{
    EXPORT_API int test(int a, int b){
        return a*b;
    }

    EXPORT_API bool InitializeApplication( HWND hwnd)
    {
        CCEGLView::SetParentHwnd(hwnd);
        CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();
        return true;
    }
}
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      [DllImport("libcc.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
      public static extern bool InitializeApplication(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("libcc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int test(int a, int b);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        Closed += MainWindow_Closed;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
       Debug.WriteLine(Multiply(3, 4).ToString()); //this runs
        InitializeApplication(wih.Handle); //this gives error
    }
}
```

so basically what i'm trying to do is to set wpf window as parent for my c++ application (which i 'packed' inside a .dll). But when i run i get "Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." exception.

sorry for my English.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `CCEGLView::SetParentHwnd(hwnd);` or `CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();`. Enable [Native Code Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx) and update your question with more details about what is going wrong at the point of failure.

Comment: yes that's it, i forgot to copy some images to the resource folder. Thank you, i didn't know that i could 'enable native code debugging', omg what a noob mistake xD

Comment: I converted my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in `CCEGLView::SetParentHwnd(hwnd);` or `CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();`. [Enable Native Code Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx) to find the source of the problem.